# jQuery effect expression engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, expressionengine

I have searched for a source which describes the steps for implementing jQuery into an expression engine site and have yet to find a good one. 
I am trying to initiate a simple slider effect for some images, using sliderPro. sliderPro has number of assets which I have uploaded into my expression js directory. Using the documented method on EE, this is how I'm calling those files:

```
    {exp:jquery:script_tag ui='core'}
    {exp:jquery:script_tag effect='sliderPro'}
    {exp:jquery:script_tag file='src/js/'}
    {exp:jquery:script_tag file='src/css/'}
    {exp:jquery:script_tag file='lib/sliderPro'}
    {exp:jquery:script_tag file='lib/fancybox/'}
```

I used all the html markup from silderPro: classes and ids for my images. When inspect Element, I do not see the passing of any of the jQuery functions? If someone could either identify what I'm missing, problem(s), or direct me to a resource which walks through the steps for implementing jQuery into an EE site, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: This may be super obvious, but have you confirmed that the jQuery module is installed?

Comment: Yes, the JQuery module is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Call me old fashioned, but what's the point of using ExpressionEngine tags for this? Far better performance (no extra database calls, no server side file lookups, utilise mutliple remote library synchronous in browser), better control and far less grief to just insert the html tags yourself - far outweights the benefit of hiding the URL to the JS resource.

According to the docs, your second line looks wrong and should be:

```
{exp:jquery:script_tag plugin='sliderPro'}
```

The effect parameter would be requesting part of the JQuery UI library, not a third-party library. Also you specify 3 folders in the script tags, the documentation states specific files without extension - not folders. I can only assume it's not working for you because all the required JS lines are not being inserted into the page. If the above changes still don't work, what does the html output result in? Are there any JS errors in the console?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slider-pro.min.css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. It is definitely a link issue. Yeah, I know that EE has a similar method for linking CSS; however, I have never used it, for some of the same reasons you mentioned here, all of which I forgot until I read your post. I think I'm going to use that old fashion method. Yes, I'm getting JS errors. After I correct the links, I'll repost the results. Thanks again.

Comment: Inspector shows that all the links are working now; however, I have 3 js errors: [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
 (anonymous function) (jquery-ui.min.js, line 6)
 global code (jquery-ui.min.js, line 6)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
 global code (jquery.fancybox.pack.js, line 46)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
 global code (jquery.sliderPro.min.js, line 7)